# Recover EXT4 partition

Tags: partitioning, ext4, data-recovery

I was trying to resize my EXT4 partition and something went wrong. I lost it. The space in once consumed is now being represented as Unallocated. How do I recover the partition?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well provided you haven't overwritten it, it's possible.

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
sudo testdisk
```

Here's a full thread showing how somebody restored their EXT4 partition (including some complications): http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1376383

Comment: Note to self: I personally had much more success with gdisk than testdisk.

Comment: cool! You saved 2TB of data for me!