# How to fix Unknown Partition in GParted

Tags: partitioning, gparted

This problem happened when I try to resize my **/dev/sda2** size (from 35 to 20 GB) and move the free space to `/dev/sda5` (data) using GParted. Unfortunately the GParted is force closed.

When I tried to open GParted again my `/dev/sda5` marked as Unknown, the screenshot below:

[image: GParted screenshot]

Below my `fdisk -l` output:

```
Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           2048   3999743   3997696   1,9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2        3999744  45943103  41943360    20G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       45944830 312579148 266634319 127,1G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5  *    80001024 312579148 232578125 110,9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       45944832  79998975  34054144  16,2G 83 Linux
```

I have tried using `testdisk` and `fsck` but have no clue how to fix this.

All my photos and documents are in `dev/sda5`.

Can anyone share how to fix this problem?

Comment: The little lock symbols say you are using gparted from your install, as they are mounted. You cannot run gparted from your install, but need to use the live installer or a gparted live ISO. Did you run fsck from live installer also. If not that can cause even more issues. http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Comment: If gparted crashed while moving a partition, it is toast.

Comment: @oldfred, I run GParted from Live Installer.

Comment: @psusi, is there any ways to make the partition work again? if I do format, can it help to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you try Testdisk's deeper search. If testdisk cannot see it then your only option is photorec or similar scan tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recover EXT4 partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1752/recover-ext4-partition)